# Python Rounding a 7 Digit Value to the nearest value of 10

Tags: python

I've been writing a program that 
 - inputs a 7 digit code

- splits it into a list

- multiplies each odd `n` valued digit, so 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th number e.g by 3 

- calculates the sum of the new lists of integers.

- rounds this sum to the nearest value of 10.

This code is shown below:

```
import math

int_input = input("Please enter your 7 digit number >> ")
int_str = list(map(int,str(int_input)))
print (int_str)
mod_list = [item * 3 if int_str % 2 == 0 else item for int_str, item in enumerate(int_str)]
print (mod_list)
tot_list = print (sum(mod_list))

print((tot_list + 9) // 10 * 10)
```

I seem to be getting this error for the value `1123456` :

```
File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
print((tot_list + 9) // 10 * 10)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

So when I type `1123456`,

```
Please enter your 7 digit number >> 1123456
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 1, 6, 3, 12, 5, 18]
48
THEN THE ERROR FROM ABOVE
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks, 
Louis.

Comment: You have a spurious print in `tot_list = print (sum(mod_list))`. `print` doesn't return a value so `tot_list` is `None`. So split this over 2 lines: `tot_list = sum(mod_list)` & `print(tot_list)`

Comment: @AChampion doesn't it print `48`?

Comment: It does print 48 but doesn't return a value to assign to `tot_list`, e.g. `print(print(5))` would print `5` `None` not `5` `5`.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you can round an integer `n` to the nearest mutiple of 10 using `round(n, -1)`.